# Set div with different height?

Tags: css, html

I'd like to know how to set different height to a div and make it responsive. I'd like to have the div with set to 100% but the left side of the div should have the height of 100px and the right side of the same div should have 120px in height. When you scale down the browser the different heights should remain even on mobile phones. Yes, there will be content in it..

[image: How I would like it to look like]

```
#myDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 200px solid blue;
    border-right: 100px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 10px solid green;
    }
```

My tries doesn't work and yes, I have googled without any luck.

Comment: Perhaps use an image to separate the two divs?

Comment: Use an image as a separator - this will give the illusion of different heights, but what you are requesting is not possible as div's only have height/width - they are rectangular/square - not trapeziums or other 4 sided shapes...

Comment: Yes. I mage two divs and the div under got an image background. In my world I thought CSS nowadays could do this easily... Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just sets the left and right border's widths, which doesn't work out in your case. The best way is to use an image and put it in the background, without a repeat.

```
.bgDiv {background: url("bg.png") center bottom no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Yepp.. I'll stick to image.. In my modern world I thought CSS could fix such easy thing.. :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The div has a shape of square or a rectangle not other so it is much better to make an image for the background and then use it like

```
#background
{
background-image:url('image.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```